# Can not import existing module into forms in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a strange import error when trying to import a module "rememberMe" in view into forms.py though the module exists. (same import statement in shell works fine).

```
 from django import forms
 from models import UserAccount, SessionLog
 from django.shortcuts import *
 from view import rememberMe

 from view import loginUser
 class loginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20, min_length=5, error_messages={'required':'Username is required'})
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=20, min_length=8, error_messages={'required':'Password is required'})
    rememberme = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

I get this error message:

```
ImportError at /
cannot import name rememberMe
```

view.py I have shortened the view.py here

```
from django.shortcuts import *
from forms import loginForm, registerForm, verifyForm
from models import UserAccount, SessionLog
import datetime, string, random
from gatherify import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

def rememberMe(response, user, is_remember):


    randomHash = getRandomHash()

    if is_remember:
        response.set_cookie('kmliCookie', randomHash, settings.COOKIE_LIFETIME)
        expiry = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=settings.COOKIE_LIFETIME)
    else:
        response.set_cookie('kmliCookie', randomHash)
        expiry = datetime.date.today()

    session = SessionLog(secretKey=randomHash, member_id=user.id, date_expiry=expiry)
    session.save();
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please define "strange import error"

Comment: ImportError at /

cannot import name rememberMe

Comment: Please post your `view.py` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular dependency: `forms` imports `view`, but `view` imports `forms`.

You haven't shown the rest of your `forms` file, but it is fairly unusual to import `views` there. Are you sure you need to?

Comment: I tried putting the "rememberMe" fn into a separate file and i tried importing it, it worked :)